# Get list of contexts in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I have several mini wars that are modules of a larger application running on a Tomcat 6.0 server.  I'm doing it this way, instead of putting all modules in one war, because different installations need different modules.  I'm starting to hit a roadblock in which I need to know what other mini wars are installed in the server.  Is there a way to get the list of all installed wars/contexts in the Tomcat 6.0 server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get a workaround to this problem since the "mini wars" that I will create can share a lib at the common class loader level in tomcat.  The trick would be to use an `ApplicationListener` (located in the common class loader) that does the following:

```
public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

  private static Map<String, ServletContext> contexts = 
    new HashMap<String,ServletContext>();

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
    if (context.getContextPath().length() > 0)
      contexts.put(context.getContextPath(), context);
    context.setAttribute("myapps", applications);
  }

}
```

When a `Context` is created it registers as a `ServletContext` in the static map.  This static map is then shared between all contexts through the `Context` variable `myapps`.  Anytime I need access to other contexts I can do the following:

```
ServletContext namedcontext = 
  ((ServletContext) ServletContext.getAttribute("myapps")).get("/namedapp");
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Isn't it context.setAttribute("myapps", contexts); ?

Comment: Did you add that code to your ApplicationListener class inside catalina.jar? or where do you put that code.

Answer (score 1):

From any one of the web applications, it is not possible.

You can use the tomcat management console which, if installed, you can access at /manager/html on the server.  This will list all of the applications installed.